# Efficient way of using Format Specifier Currency C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating a simple console app which I use the Currency format specifier. But I want it to be the sharpest way.

I've done this way:

```cs
class Account
{
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Holder { get; set; }
        public double Balance { get; protected set; }

        public Account(int number, string holder, double balance)
        {
            Number = number;
            Holder = holder;
            Balance = balance;
        }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
       Account acc = new Account(8010, "Bob", 100);

       Console.WriteLine($"{acc.Balance:C}");
}
```

I want to know if this is the lesser typing and best way of doing it. What do you guys think?

Comment: There are no performance issues here. You're fine.

Comment: For financial and monetary calculation, [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) could be more appropriate

Comment: Less typing than what?  `C`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear which part of your code you're seeking a shorter way to implement, but since you mention the currency format specifier a couple times I assume your question boils down to simply...

> Is there a shorter way than this to write a currency-formatted number
>   to the console?
>
> ```
> double balance = 100;
>
> Console.WriteLine($"{balance:C}");
> ```

There are a few options that produce the same result...

```
Console.WriteLine($"{balance:C}");
Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", balance);
Console.WriteLine(balance.ToString("C"));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:C}", balance));
```

...but one can't really expect to get much shorter than an interpolated string with a single-character format specifier.

Note that all of the above format a currency string using the [culture of the current thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture).  If you want to [perform formatting using a specific culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types#culture-sensitive-formatting-with-format-providers-and-the-iformatprovider-interface) then your options become fewer and longer...

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

Console.WriteLine(balance.ToString("C", culture));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(culture, "{0:C}", balance));
```

As @NicoD pointed out in the comments, for storing currency you'll also want to look into using the `decimal` type instead of `float` or `double`:

- [Decimal Structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.decimal#remarks)
- [Difference between decimal, float and double in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/618535/150605)
- [decimal vs double! - Which one should I use and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1165761/150605)
- [How to decide what to use - double or decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6341855/150605)